# Spacy incorrectly identifying pronouns

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

When I try this code using Spacy, I get the desired result:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# example 1
test = "All my stuff is at to MyBOQ"
doc = nlp(test)
for word in doc:
    if word.pos_ == 'PRON':
        print(word.text)
```

The output shows `All` and `my`. However, if I add a question mark:

```
test = "All my stuff is at to MyBOQ?"
doc = nlp(test)
for word in doc:
    if word.pos_ == 'PRON':
        print(word.text)
```

now it also identifies `MyBOQ` as a pronoun. It should be classified as an organization name (`word.pos_ == 'ORG'`) instead.

How do I tell Spacy not to classify MyBOQ as a pronoun? Should I just remove all punctuation before checking for pronouns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running your code on my machine (Windows 11 64-bit, Python 3.10.9, spaCy 3.4.4), spaCy produces the following results for the text with and without the question mark:

```
                               en_core_web_sm   en_core_web_md   en_core_web_trf
All my stuff is at to MyBOQ?   All, my          my               my
All my stuff is at to MyBOQ    All, my          my               my
```

In this example, the word "All" is not a pronoun but rather a determiner, so only the `en_core_web_md` and `en_core_web_trf` pipelines are producing technically correct results. If you're running an old version of spaCy I'd suggest updating the package. Alternatively, if spaCy is up-to-date, try restarting your IDE/computer to see if it stops producing erroneous results---there should be no need to remove punctuation before checking for pronouns.

Finally, [Part of Speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech#Types_of_Part_of_Speech) (PoS) tags do not include organisation names (`ORG`). I think you're mixing [Named Entity](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#annotations-ner) tags with PoS tags. "MyBOQ" should be PoS tagged as a proper noun (`PROPN`) which the `en_core_web_md` and `en_core_web_trf` pipelines identify correctly, whereas `en_core_web_sm` pipeline does not (instead tagging it as a basic `NOUN`).